# api json data fetch from url

Tags: php, json

pls all i have this code that outputs a json data

```
echo json_encode(array(
                        "amount" => $user->amount,
                        "Sender" => $decoded->data->phone,
                        "Bank" => $user->bank,
                        "acct_number" => $user->acct,
                        "remarks" => $user->remarks,
                        "acct_name" => $user->receiver,

                    )
```

i would love to get the data it outputs from another url, meanwhile my full code is below pls help me with this

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/kio/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 60");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// files needed to connect to database
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/user.php';


// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// instantiate user object
$user = new User($db);

// check email existence here
// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set product property values
$token=isset($data->token) ? $data->token : "";
$user->id = $data->id;
$user->pin = $data->pin;
$user->bank = $data->bank;
$user->acct = $data->acct;
$user->remarks = $data->remarks;
$user->receiver = $data->receiver;

$transaction = $user->Transaction();

// files for jwt will be here
// generate json web token
include_once '../config/core.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/BeforeValidException.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/ExpiredException.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/JWT.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;



            if ($token) {

                try {
                    $decoded = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));



                    try {

                if ($transaction && ($data->pin == $user->pin)) {



               // set response code and assign the user phone as user id


                http_response_code(200);

                echo json_encode(array(
                        "amount" => $user->amount,
                        "Sender" => $decoded->data->phone,
                        "Bank" => $user->bank,
                        "acct_number" => $user->acct,
                        "remarks" => $user->remarks,
                        "acct_name" => $user->receiver,

                    )
                );
            }

            else{

                http_response_code(400);

             // tell the user access denied  & show error message
             echo json_encode(
                array("Sever Response", 
                array
             ("message" => "Invalid Card Pin/ Card Used")
            ));
            }

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                // set response code
             http_response_code(407);

            // tell the user access denied  & show error message
            echo json_encode(array(
             "response" => "Access denied.",
             "error" => $e->getMessage()
    ));

            }

                }

                 catch (Exception $e) {

                      // set response code
    http_response_code(406);

    // tell the user access denied  & show error message
    echo json_encode(array(
        "response" => "Access denied.",
        "error" => $e->getMessage()
    ));

                }

            }

            else{

    // set response code
    http_response_code(363);

    // tell the user access denied
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "error"));
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? Do you want to get the json output to another file or function?

Comment: it's unclear what you want us to tell you. Above is your code to output the data. It will be available at whatever URL points to this PHP code. e.g. something like `www.example.com/yourscript.php` . So if you call that URL (either in your browser, or from some other code) with valid input data then you'll get the data returned. Are you asking us how to make a HTTP request from some other code to get this data? If so then you'll need to tell us what language/environment you're writing your other program in. To be honest though you can google the basics of that easily already.

Comment: i want to make a request to this from another script using another script written in PHP. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok so see Abhishek's example in the answer below. Or you can use cURL as the client instead. What have you actually researched or tried? It's not hard to find out how to make a HTTP request using PHP.

Comment: Have you tried? Have you encountered a specific difficulty? If so, post your attempt and explain what problem you're facing. We're not really here to help you do the basic research into your requirement (especially when it's something very common and well-understood like "make a http request from PHP"), instead we'll assist when you have a direct problem you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can get json response from an API (url) by using

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

The function takes a URL as a parameter. `$json` will be a json object ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)).

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

The `json_decode()` will convert the json object to an array. You can manipulate the data in the array.